# EventMachine::WebSocketClient.connect causes onclose to trigger on server side

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inter-process-communicat, em-websocket, em-websocket-client

There are three parts in my Rails application:

- A part which listens for HTML5 web sockets ([em-websocket](https://github.com/igrigorik/em-websocket))
- a piece of JavaScript which connects to them
- and a part which task is to connect to these sockets from inside of the same web application ([em-websocket-client](https://github.com/mwylde/em-websocket-client)) (Yes, I am trying to do some IPC in Phusion Passenger environment)

JavaScript code connects fine and Web sockets server is happy with such a client, but when I connect from `em-websocket-client` a strange thing is happening: `onclose` handler is being called without calling `onopen`, and moreover - it is called for a socket which had been opened by web browser, not `em-websocket-client`.

The same `em-websocket-client` code, when executed in separate Ruby script through command line, works as planned. Here is the sample of `em-websocket-client` code:

```
require 'em-websocket-client'

class WebSocketsClient
  def initialize
    Thread.new do
      log 'In a thread'
      EventMachine.run do
        log 'EM run'
        @conn = EventMachine::WebSocketClient.connect("ws://localhost:5050?user_id=1&page_token=JYUTbfYDTTliglififi")

        @conn.callback do
          log 'Callback'
          @conn.send_msg({ message_type: 'phone_call', user_id: 1, order_id: 1}.to_json)
          @conn.close_connection
        end

        @conn.errback do |e|
          log 'Errback'
          puts "Got error: #{e}"
        end

        @conn.stream do |msg|
          #log 'Stream'
          #puts "<#{msg}>"
          #if msg.data == 'done'
          #  @conn.close_connection
          #end
        end

        @conn.disconnect do
          puts 'gone'
          EventMachine::stop_event_loop
        end
      end
    end
  end

  def send_phone_call(order_id, user_id)
    @conn.send_msg({ message_type: 'phone_call', user_id: user_id, order_id: order_id}.to_json)
  end

  def log(text)
    puts "WebSocketsClient: #{text}\n"
  end
end


WebSocketsClient.new
```

`onclose` on server side is being callsd as soon as `EventMachine::WebSocketClient.connect` is executed on client side. It doesn't even come to `@conn.disconnect` call.

One more thing I can conjecture is that this behaviour is due to using same `EventMachine` mechanism by server and client inside of same Rails application.